# Mapping Folders and Sites in Laravel/Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, homestead

I have slowly been working on getting Laravel/Homestead up on ubuntu 15.1 and am struggling to get my folders and sites mapped in my Homestead.yaml file. The virtual machine is up and running, when I go to Homestead.app in the browser it tells me that no input file specified. I know that I don't have it mapped correctly.

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/Homestead/Projects/Laravel
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects

 sites:
  - map: homestead.app
  to: /home/goldenos/Homestead/Projects/public

 databases:
- homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports: 
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

I have my index.php file in ~/Homestead/Projects in a folder named Laravel if I need to provide any additional information please let me know and I will provide it asap. Thanks in advance for any information!
-Luke

Comment: You're moving to 15.1 too slowly, it's already [past end of life](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life), so you should start on moving to 16.04 before 2021

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try THIS instead:

```
folders:
  - map: ~/Homestead/Projects // your local whole projects folder on the host machine (so you can setup multiple websites on the same virtual box)
    to: /home/vagrant/Projects // synced folder in virtual box

sites:
  - map: homestead.app
    to: /home/vagrant/Projects/Laravel/public // path of project in the virtual box
  - map: site2.app
    to: /home/vagrant/Projects/Site2/public
```

Don't forget to run vagrant up/reload flagging --provision after you edited your .yaml file like:

```
vagrant up --provision
```

OR

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Comment: `vagrant reload --provision`

was what did it for me! Thanks! :-)